# Esconder div sem dar reload

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Boa tarde, preciso fazer uma function de click sem que o navegador seja atualizado

```
 const show = document.querySelectorAll('.show_button')
 const selector = document.querySelector('.information')

   for (let bottom of show) {
     bottom.addEventListener("click", function(){
      selector.classList.add('hidden')
       location.reload(false)
      })
  }



       <div class="mostrar">
            <div class="ingredients">
                <h2>Modo de Preparo</h2>             
            </div>
            <div class="show_button">
                <button id="meu_botao" class='handle-div' type="button">ESCONDER</button> 
                <button id="meu_botao" class='handle-div' type="button">MOSTRAR</button>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Porém cada vem que eu clico para esconder a DIV, ele fica dando reload ná pagina. Estou usando o Firefox e como back-end o Node.js, não sei se isso influência

Comment: Está dando reload por causa desta linha: `location.reload(false)`. Isso é intencional?

Comment: Eu tinha colocado para ver se parava o reload... Mas continua da mesma forma, com ou sem ele

Comment: Então acho que vale [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes, porque atualmente a única causa de um possível _reload_ seria aquela linha.